# MYSQL Select values of sub query result in main query

Tags: mysql, sql

My sql query is

```
 SELECT c_id
      , name
      , stu_id 
      , option_id
      , expiration_status 
      , expiration_date_type 
      , expiration_date_val 
   FROM options 
  WHERE option_id 
     IN 
      ( SELECT  option_id 
          FROM registration WHERE status NOT in ('C','T')
           AND structure = 'C' 
      ) 
  ORDER 
     BY structure
      , option_id ASC
```

Here i want to select list of option_id which are selected in sub query as a new column in main query

Comment: Your sql seems invalid due to you put `*` before `select` in your sub query

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `INNER JOIN` to do it

```
SELECT o.c_id,o.name,o.stu_id ,o.option_id,o.expiration_status , 
 o.expiration_date_type , o.expiration_date_val
FROM `options` o
JOIN `registration` r ON r.option_id=o.option_id AND  r.status NOT in ('C','T')
    AND r.structure = 'C' 
    ORDER BY o.structure, o.option_id ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

use join instead on `in` and put the column name as you need from sub-query

```
SELECT `c_id`,`name`,`stu_id` ,`option_id`,`expiration_status` , `expiration_date_type` , `expiration_date_val`, t1.option_id as new_col
FROM `options` o  
 left join (
    SELECT  `option_id` 
    FROM `registration` 
    WHERE `status` NOT in ('C','T')
    AND `structure` = 'C' 
     ) t1 on o.option_id=t1.option_id
ORDER BY o.`structure`, o.`option_id` ASC
```